# Imprimir objecto json con buen fromato

Tags: java

tengo la siguiente función que lo que hace es traerme una lista desde el webservice, después esa lista la convierto en un string XML ya que la lista que me devuelve es una respuesta soap. despues de eso lo que hago ese string pasarlo a json y obtengo algo como esto.

`{"ListaMaterias":[{"nombreMateria":"Biologia","codigoMateria":3525,"id":1,"descMateria":"Aprender Biologia"},{"nombreMateria":"Quimica","codigoMateria":3678,"id":2,"descMateria":"Aprender Quimica"}]}`

Como puedo hacer para darle un mejor formato de impresion al objeto json. por ejemplo imprimirlo como especie de tabla ?

código de la función:

```
'    public static void main(String[] args) {

    List resultado = null; 
    resultado = new ArrayList<>();
    resultado = listarDatos();
    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    String xml = xstream.toXML(resultado);

    String xml_m = xml.replace("<list>", "").replace("</list>", "").replace("<newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "<ListaMaterias>").replace("</newwebservicematerias.Materia>", "</ListaMaterias>");

    JSONObject soapDatainJsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml_m);
    System.out.println(soapDatainJsonObject);

    /*Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(soapDatainJsonObject);
    System.out.println(jsonString);*/

}'
```

Comment: Podrías intentar con la `Interface JsonParser ` de Java. En la documentación de java te puede ayudar a entender un poco mejor como darle formato a los objetos del JSON. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html